# user enters price in input field .. select box with auto range

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Ok. Still busily figuring out our form, etc. So scenario. We have a form for member to enter a price. Typically, they would enter anything between 50,000 and 10,000,000. We also have select drop-down, with value ranges.

Example of the form so far:

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="propertyprice">Price</label>
  <input id="currency" name="limitedtextfield" size="50" type="text" class="medium" onKeyPress="return numbersonly(event, false)" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.limitedtextfield,this.form,8);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.limitedtextfield,this.form,8);" maxlength="8"/>
  <p class="field_help">Enter only numbers.</p>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <label for="propertypricerange">Price Range </label>
  <select id="propertypricerange" name="propertypricerange" class="medium">
    <optgroup label="Enter Price Range">
    <option selected="selected" value="0balance">0    -    $100,000</option>
    <option value="100kmin">$100,000    -    $200,000</option>
    <option value="200kmin">$200,000    -    $300,000</option>
    <option value="300kmin">$300,000    -    $400,000</option>
    <option value="400kmin">$400,000    -    $500,000</option>
    <option value="500kmin">$500,000    -    $600,000</option>
    <option value="600kmin">$600,000    -    $700,000</option>
    <option value="700kmin">$700,000    -    $800,000</option>
    <option value="800kmin">$800,000    -    $900,000</option>
    <option value="900kmin">$900,000    -    $1,000,000</option>
    <option value="1milmin">$1,000,000    -    $2,000,000</option>
    <option value="2milmin">$2,000,000    -    $3,000,000</option>
    <option value="3milmin">$3,000,000    -    $4,000,000</option>
    <option value="4milmin">$4,000,000    -    $5,000,000</option>
    <option value="5milmin">$5,000,000    -    $10,000,000</option>
    <option value="10milplus">$10,000,000    -    +</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

What I would like to do, is the select price ranges automatically select the range that the users types in. There is no need to disable the select ranges, because we don't always need member to type in a price in input field, but we would like them to then select a range. So a kinda vice versa form.

Anyone ever done anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Here's a non-looping version. Simply uses arithmetic.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/uv8Jh/4/

```
var sel = $('#propertypricerange')[0];

function findRange(val) {
    return ( val < 1000000 ) ? (val - val % 100000) / 100000 :
           ( val < 10000000 ) ? Math.min((val - val % 1000000) / 1000000 + 9, 14) :
            15;    
}
$('#currency').keyup(function() {
    sel.selectedIndex = findRange(this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,''));
});
```

---

**Original Answer:**

Here's one solution, though it may need a little code to ensure that only numbers are entered into the input.

Doesn't rely on keycodes. Just compares the input value to the values that have been stored in an array.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/uv8Jh/1/

```
   // cache the select list
var sel = $('#propertypricerange')[0];
   // Make an array of the values
var values = $.map( sel.options, function(opt) {
    return (opt.value.indexOf('kmin') > -1) ?
        parseInt(opt.value) * 1000 :
        parseInt(opt.value) * 1000000;
});
  // receive the current value and return the index of the proper range
function findRange( val ) {
    var i = 0, len = values.length;
    while( i++ < len ) {
        if( val < values[ i ] ) {
            return i-1;
        }
    }
    return len - 1;
}
   // set the proper range on keyup event
$('#currency').keyup(function() {
    sel.selectedIndex = findRange( this.value );
});
```

Again, there should be some cleanup in case the user types an invalid character. Simple regex should do it.

---

**EDIT:** Here's the key event with a little checking for invalid characters.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/uv8Jh/2/

```
$('#currency').keyup(function() {
    sel.selectedIndex = findRange(this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,''));
});
```

Comment: cheers Patrick, thats nigh on it. The character restriction , text limiter we already have built in. It isnt selecting the amounts correctly for us, essentially I think we have a conflict with our number to currency thang. Which I will disable and try and find a workaround

Comment: Yeah that didnt do it, perhaps is another issue ( if you click the select drop down box, the correct range is Highlighted in the list, but isnt focused as your jsfiddle example. Bugger

Comment: @422 - Is your other code manipulating the input in any other way, like adding commas or something? The only valid characters should be numbers and decimal point.

Comment: yes, it adds commas, so changes the output from 123456 to $123,456

Comment: @422 - Wanted to see if you got this worked out. I see the accepted answer posted a near identical solution after I posted this one. Only difference is that I didn't realize changing the `<option>` values was ok. Mine converts them manually to an Array.

Comment: @422 - Added another version to the top of my answer. Doesn't require any looping, but modifies the values of the `<option>` elements if that's alright.

Comment: Our issue is getting it to work, harmoniously with our mashup. Thanks, still have issues. But think we will have to shelve this idea.

Answer (score 2):

This works on your current code for values up to 9:

```
function findRange(e) {
   !e ? e = window.event : null;
   if(e.keyCode >=48 && e.keyCode <=57) {
     $('propertypricerange').selectedIndex = e.keyCode - 48;
   }
 }

 $('propertypricerange').onkeyup = findRange;
```

With values for 1 million and above, the user will have to type in more than one key, and also the Javascript will have to remember more than one key, so you may need an input box for that. If you don't want an input box, here's a variation on the code above that will remember as multiple values and select that index (e.g., type "1", "2" and you'll see index 12, backspace, you'll see index 1)

```
 var val = [];
 function findRange(e) {
   !e ? e = window.event : null;
   if(e.keyCode==8) {
     val.pop();
     $('propertypricerange').selectedIndex = val.join("");
   }

   if(e.keyCode >=48 && e.keyCode <=57) {
     val.push(e.keyCode - 48);
     $('propertypricerange').selectedIndex = val.join("");
   }
 }

 $('propertypricerange').onkeyup = findRange;
```

Comment: still trying to adapt this into working code, :) to get feel for it

Comment: This won't work with the numpad, by the way, just the upper number keys.  Working on something better, one sec.

Comment: OK, see my next answer for full solution. Supports number keys, numpad, and multiple-character entry, with backspace to remove. Entering 2-0-backspace will give you 200,000 - 2,000,000 - 200,000. Works in IE and FF.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you store the range values in a javascript var - if your ranges will never intersect, you can just use an array of the start values.  Then, every time the onchange event is fired for the input box -

- Parse the value of the input box to a number
- Loop through the array of start points until you find a value which is greater than your parsed number and subtract 1 from the index.
- Change the selectedindex of the select box to the appropriate index.

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy...

Rename your option IDs to something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="text-value" value="0" name="text-value" />
  <select id="select-list" name="select-list">
    <option id="min_100" value="100kmin">$100,000    -    $200,000</option>
    <option id="min_200" value="200kmin">$200,000    -    $300,000</option>
    ...
  </select>

$(function(){
  $('#select-list').change(function(){
    var _id = $(this).val().split('_');
    $('#text-value').val('$'+_id[1]+',000');
  });
});
```

Searching for the right selection can use the same method.

Comment: I think it's the other way around. OP wants the range from the select to be chose as the user types a number in the text field.

Comment: As @patrick dw says, we need the select box to select the range that suits the input typed in.

Answer (score 1):

Full rewrite here.  Supports number keys, numpad, and multiple-character entry, with backspace to remove. Entering 2-0-backspace will give you 200,000 - 2,000,000 - 200,000. Works in IE and FF.  Does not need `input` field, just focus the drop down and type.

HTML, values adjusted for ease in Javascript:

```
<optgroup label="Enter Price Range">
  <option selected="selected" value="0balance">0    -    $100,000</option>
  <option value="1">$100,000    -    $200,000</option>
  <option value="2">$200,000    -    $300,000</option>
  <option value="3">$300,000    -    $400,000</option>
  <option value="4">$400,000    -    $500,000</option>
  <option value="5">$500,000    -    $600,000</option>
  <option value="6">$600,000    -    $700,000</option>
  <option value="7">$700,000    -    $800,000</option>
  <option value="8">$800,000    -    $900,000</option>
  <option value="9">$900,000    -    $1,000,000</option>
  <option value="10">$1,000,000    -    $2,000,000</option>
  <option value="20">$2,000,000    -    $3,000,000</option>
  <option value="30">$3,000,000    -    $4,000,000</option>
  <option value="40">$4,000,000    -    $5,000,000</option>
  <option value="50">$5,000,000    -    $10,000,000</option>
  <option value="100">$10,000,000    -    +</option>
</optgroup>
```

Javascript:

```
//Keypress storage
var val = [];

//Keypress manager function
function findRange(e) {
  !e ? e = window.event : null;
  $('out').innerHTML = e.keyCode   // SORRY REMOVE THIS LINE (testing only)

  //Enable backspacing
  if(e.keyCode==8) {
    val.pop();
    findIndex();
  }

  //Enable keyboard numbers
  if(e.keyCode >=48 && e.keyCode <=57) {
    val.push(e.keyCode - 48);
    findIndex();
  }

  //Enable numpad numbers
  if(e.keyCode >=96 && e.keyCode <=105) {
    val.push(e.keyCode - 96);
    findIndex();
  }
}

//Dropdown option value finder
function findIndex() {
  var opts = $('propertypricerange').options;
  for(x=0;x<opts.length;x++) {
    if(opts[x].value == val.join("")) {
      $('propertypricerange').selectedIndex = x;
      break;
    }
  }
}

//Event
$('propertypricerange').onkeyup = findRange;
```

**EDIT**

Accepted solution actually refers to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/steve/nB68u/), from the comments.

Comment: Oooh Steve you are good, gonna give it a whirl now, buddy thanks. BRB

Comment: Whoops sorry left `$('out')`. Remove that it was for testing only.

Comment: The `$()` function isn't included, and you don't need the input box anymore. Here's the working example (exactly as above, plus the $ function from JQuery) http://jsfiddle.net/steve/L4REK/.  Focus on the drop down, and type a number or two.

Comment: cheers Steve, not quite what we wanted, but can think of a great use for that. So sweet, thanks :)

Comment: Cheers Steve , thats better. Its interfering with other js on the page tho, which is probably due to similarly named id's I suppose. This does look cleaner and easier to use, thanks :)

Comment: Thank you too.  One thing to keep in mind is that the `input` solution is a little more clunky for the user since they'd have to enter at least 5 keystrokes to get it to change.